# SQL Server : how to do two action at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
if (SELECT * FROM SDOPTTABLE WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324' AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578') = null
    insert into SDOPTTABLE(comp_cd, opttableno, opttableval, optname, dt_stamp) 
    values ('1','324','00883578','STOCKROOM ATTENDANT',getdate())

SELECT * FROM SDOPTTABLE WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324' AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578'
else
    (SELECT * FROM SDOPTTABLE WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324' AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578')
```

I want to do "select" again from the 'SDOPTTABLE' table after i verify and already inserted the data input which was not exist.

can anyone show me the correct method to do this? thanks.

---

the code i have

```
INSERT  INTO HCSERVREC (COMP_CD, JOBTL_CD, JOBGD_CD)
select               '1', ( if NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM SDOPTTABLE
    WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324'
        AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578'
    )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SDOPTTABLE (
    comp_cd
    ,opttableno
    ,opttableval
    ,optname
    ,dt_stamp
    )
VALUES (
    '1'
    ,'324'
    ,'00883578'
    ,'STOCKROOM ATTENDANT'
    ,getdate()
    )
END

SELECT *
FROM SDOPTTABLE
WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324'
AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578'), '[$9]'
```

can you point me the wrong spot?

Comment: Two things: **(1)** don't use `= NULL` to check for null - use `IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`) instead! And **(2)** if you want to execute more than one statement in an `IF` branch - you need to put your statements into a `BEGIN.....END` block

Comment: IF EXISTS() is a nice one here... I have to admit though, when it comes to putting procedural (if/else) code into SQL I usually start thinking I'm doing something wrong and backtrack to find out what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM SDOPTTABLE
        WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324'
            AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578'
        )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SDOPTTABLE (
        comp_cd
        ,opttableno
        ,opttableval
        ,optname
        ,dt_stamp
        )
    VALUES (
        '1'
        ,'324'
        ,'00883578'
        ,'STOCKROOM ATTENDANT'
        ,getdate()
        )
END

SELECT *
FROM SDOPTTABLE
WHERE OPTTABLENO = '324'
    AND OPTTABLEVAL = '00883578'
```

Comment: Hi bro Thanks for the quick and correct reply! its works! but there are something i do not understand, i hope i could get some explanation from you. what is different "select 1" and "select Top 1"?

Comment: @Jelly: There is no difference in exists statement if you write "Select 1" or "Select top 1" bcs once any record is found then it'll satisfied your if condition and insert the record

Comment: i meet another problem when i was going to put this statement into another another "Insert" statement ,become one of the VALUES input, it become error which happened in the "IF".

Comment: @Jelly: OK what exactly you want to do ?? you can't use if statement in insert query like this. Your posted query is totally wrong.

Comment: actually my main statement is doing insertion.and some of the VALUES input, i need to do verify before insert it, thats why i do the select on certain data input which if needed.  (sorry i hope you can understand my bad language)

Comment: so how i should use if statement in insert query? @Krishnraj Rana